# The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I Copied this code from a video, but I am getting this error : *The parameter 'id' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CataologModel {
  static final items = [
    Item(
      1,    //ERROR on this line
      "iPhone 12",
      "Apple 12th Gen",
      999,
      "White",
      "assets/images/iphone12b.jpg",
    )
  ];
}

class Item {
  final num id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final num price;
  final String color;
  final String image;

  Item({this.id, this.name, this.desc, this.price, this.color, this.image}); //ERROR on this line

  factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Item(
      id: map["id"],
      name: map["name"],
      desc: map["desc"],
      price: map["price"],
      color: map["color"],
      image: map["image"],
    );
  }

  toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "desc": desc,
        "price": price,
        "color": color,
        "image": image,
      };
}
```

[image: Code ScreenShot]

And Also this error at the beginning :

[image: 2nd Error ScreenShot]

Even if I use 'required' in parameters as required, I get this new error and cant resolve them.

[image: ERROR 3 if added Required]

Note: I am new to Flutter

I copied the code but it's not working as shown in video, it may be because of Null Safety, and as I am new, I don't know much about Null Safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being null-safety final not nullable fields needed to be required on constructor.

```dart
  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.desc,
    required this.price,
    required this.color,
    required this.image,
  });
```

And you are using named argument, which used like

```dart
  Item(
      id: 1, 
      name: "iPhone 12",
      desc: "Apple 12th Gen",
      price: 999,
      color: "White",
      image: "assets/images/iphone12b.jpg",
    )
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).